# Rails 3 delayed_job start after rebooting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have my rails site deployed under apache. The apache is run as a service. Now I have added delayed_job there and things work fine.

Now I want to start the workers together with apache, e.g, After rebooting the server, my site and workers are up and ready so I don't have to log in and type "sudo RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 start".

Another issue is that whenever I want to start the delayed_job I have to use "sudo"...

Any idea how to avoid those 2 issues?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) and its 'every :reboot' functionality. In schedule.rb:

```
environment = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'
every :reboot do
    command "cd #{path} && #{environment_variable}=#{environment} bin/delayed_job --pool=queue1:2, --pool=queue2,queue3:1 restart"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you just create a shell script to execute the commands you need?

```
#!/bin/sh

# stop delayed job

# restart apache
apachectl restart

# start delayed job
sudo RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 start
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to have delayed_job automatically start after apache starts when you boot up the hardware. If that's the case you need to write an init script in `/etc/init.d` or `/etc/rc.d/init.d` (depending on your system). This page gives a decent primer on this:

http://www.philchen.com/2007/06/04/quick-and-dirty-how-to-write-and-init-script